# In winform, how to add sort column functionaity into listview columns?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, listview, sorting

In winform, how to add sort column functionaity into listview columns ?

I could not find any properity for column which allows>

Thanks

Comment: Here's a nice article on MSDN that explains how to do this: [**Sorting ListView Items by Column Using Windows Forms**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996467.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write your own class that implements `IComparer`.

You then write a Compare method that Implements `IComparer.Compare` in this class.

Below is an example of one I wrote some time ago that sorts by number, date or string but you can modify this for your own use:

```
Public Class ListViewComparer
    Implements IComparer

    Private _columnNumber As Integer
    Private _sortOrder As SortOrder

    Public Sub New(ByVal colIndex As Integer, ByVal sortingOrder As SortOrder)
        _columnNumber = colIndex
        _sortOrder = sortingOrder
    End Sub

    ' Compare the items in the appropriate column
    ' for objects x and y.
    Public Function Compare(ByVal x As Object, ByVal y As Object) As Integer Implements System.Collections.IComparer.Compare
        Dim itemX As ListViewItem = DirectCast(x, ListViewItem)
        Dim itemY As ListViewItem = DirectCast(y, ListViewItem)
        Dim stringX As String = "", stringY As String = ""
        ' Get the sub-item values.

        If itemX.SubItems.Count > _columnNumber Then stringX = itemX.SubItems(_columnNumber).Text
        If itemY.SubItems.Count > _columnNumber Then stringY = itemY.SubItems(_columnNumber).Text

        ' Compare them.
        If _sortOrder = SortOrder.Ascending Then
            If IsNumeric(stringX) And IsNumeric(stringY) Then
                Return CInt(stringX).CompareTo(CInt(stringY))
            ElseIf IsDate(stringX) And IsDate(stringY) Then
                Return DateTime.Parse(stringX).CompareTo(DateTime.Parse(stringY))
            Else
                Return String.Compare(stringX, stringY)
            End If
        Else
            If IsNumeric(stringX) And IsNumeric(stringY) Then
                Return CInt(stringY).CompareTo(CInt(stringX))
            ElseIf IsDate(stringX) And IsDate(stringY) Then
                Return DateTime.Parse(stringY).CompareTo(DateTime.Parse(stringX))
            Else
                Return String.Compare(stringY, stringX)
            End If
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

Usage:

```
ListViewControl1.ListViewItemSorter = New ListViewComparer(2, SortOrder.Ascending)
ListViewControl1.Sort()
```

Comment: No, you will have to call the sort code in the ` ListView1.ColumnClick` event and pass in the `e.Column` value

Comment: ok, its working. But, how to manage ascending and descending both.. on related click.

Comment: you need to keep track of which direction you are currently sorting in and reverse it on a click of the same column. If you click a different column then set it back to ascending